# difference between Meucci fully flexible probability and markov regime swtiching models?

Tags: portfolio-management, tactical-asset-allocation, markov-switching, entropy-pooling

What is the difference between A. Meucci's Fully Flexible Probability ([FFP](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1696802)) and Markov Regime Switching Models ? They seem very similar to me, FFP based on state variables that define regimes will derive probabilities that will weight historical asset class returns more or less and Markov regime switching models will also do the same ?